# Loading realtime database items with the CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

After following [this firebase guide](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/read-and-write-your-realtime-database.html), I can run the command below to update my `realtime database`.

```
firebase database:push /myStuffs data.json
```

Where the contents of the data.json file is:

```
{
    "name":"Doug",
    "text":"I love Firebase"
}
```

But it no longer runs if the contents of the data.json file is:

```
{
    "name":"Doug",
    "text":"I love Firebase"
},
{
    "name":"Donald",
    "text":"Make Firebase great again"
}
```

Obviously, there are cases where one would appreciate being able to load several items with one command. So the question is what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was not lucky enough to get an answer with some proper way to handle this.

I ended up by building my own solution. Thinking it may well be useful for someone else in the future. Here is the [link to see the details](http://www.sofisfun.net/IT/ReTiDaBaAuLo.html).